# PictureBox.Size property is unaffected by assignment

Tags: c#, resize, picturebox

I've got a `PictureBox` which is inside `tableLayoutPanel3` when I select a file from `Listbox` I resize the `pictureBox` to the size of an image:

```
private void imageListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(imageListBox.Items[0]);
        string imagePath = imageListBox.SelectedItem + "";
        Bitmap = new Bitmap(imagePath);
        pictureBox.Image = Bitmap;
        pictureBox.Size = Bitmap.Size;//doesn't change pictureBox's size
        //those two sizes below are different
        Debug.WriteLine(Bitmap.Width + " " + Bitmap.Height);
        Debug.WriteLine(pictureBox.Width + " " + pictureBox.Height);
        Invalidate();
    }
```

[image: Designer]

[image: result]

**Question:** How to resize the pictureBox so it fits the image inside?

My dirty solution, I manged to resolve the problem by:
`this.Size = new Size(tableLayoutPanel2.Width + Bitmap.Size.Width, Bitmap.Height);` but in my opinion this is a wrong way.

EDIT: I've tried every `PictureBox.SizeMode` value available.

Comment: What about using PictureBox's SizeMode property? e.g. With StretchImage? Or AutoSize?

Comment: @Pikoh I've already tried those, they don't affect pictureBox size in any way.

Comment: Yoda, of course AutoSize mode change the picturebox to the size of the bitmap...I've just tried it. Maybe is the tableLayout what is not changing its size

Comment: @Pikoh It is designed to do it, so it might do it in most cases, it fails in mine. This is the project: `Adrian16Image` http://www78.zippyshare.com/v/7kBQGFBz/file.html
 contains the code, it's in english. Thanks.

Comment: Setting the Size property has no effect on a control that is docked.

Comment: @HansPassant I undocked it with no success.

Comment: Have you tried what i explain in my answer?

Comment: I can't see the size of the PictureBox in your image. set its Border to 3d for testing!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First, set the SizeMode to Autosize:

```
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Then what you have to do is to modifiy this properties:

- In the 3 TableLayoutPanels you have, set `AutoSize=true`.
- The column definition in your TableLayoutPanel1 must have the first column with a Absolute value of x pixels, and the second with 100% percent.

You have also to undock your TableLayoutPanel,set Form `AutoSize` to `true` and `AutoSizeMode`to `GrowAndShrink`.

This way the layout you've got will grow accordingly with your bitmap

Comment: Thank you for nice answer, unfortunately, tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: I removed `tableLayout3` : this is my project http://www68.zippyshare.com/v/QrQmUGip/file.html

Comment: @Yoda I've downloaded your project and it resizes everything ok except for the form. Is that what you were talking about? is the form what doesn't get resized???

Comment: @Yoda I've uploaded a working version of your proyect (in .Net4.0 as i don't have access now to anything but VS2010) [here](http://www18.zippyshare.com/v/fNYUEDEV/file.html). It's basically doing exactly what i've explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try auto size:

```
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```